# Is something wrong with the .each iterator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I launched the index page 
below, the text was printed 6 times. Don't know why. I'm a newbie on rails. I've already defined them on migration.

```
<% @controls.each do |t| %>
  <%= t.home %>
  <%= t.services %>
  <%= t.contact %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my `seeds.rb`

```
a1 = Control.create(home: "Home", services: "Services", contact: "Contact")
```

Controller code

```
def index
  @controls = Control.all
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run `rake db:seed` multiple times. You can get around that by updating your seeds file like this

```
Control.delete_all
a1 = Control.create(home: "Home", services: "Services", contact: "Contact")
```

or like this, which only creates a new item in the db if there isn't one already.

```
Control.find_or_create_by(home: "Home", services: "Services", contact: "Contact")
```

Then you're free to run `rake db:seed` as often as you want.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: No. Have you restarted your app roughly six times after putting that `seeds.rb` in? I would bet that you have.

You are not ever removing the data after you insert it, so each time you run `seeds.rb` it will add a new record, never clearing out previous ones.